# Gathering mac addresses with Python

Tags: python, django, networking, mac-address

is there a good way to gather the mac addresses of machines on a local network using Python.  If it helps I'm trying to execute this python script from the DHCP server for the network. I'm new to Python but would it be a bad idea to look at the DHCP leases file for this info? I'd like to use this inside a Django app eventually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to run a tool that can achieve this and parse its output (e.g. nmap). Depending on your needs, you could run it periodically and keep a file with the mac addresses. 
Looking at the leases file could work, assuming that all your machines are in there. If you want to actively look for machines, do a nmap scan.

Answer (score 1):

Really a unix question (one will assume)

You can either look at the arp addresses registered "/sbin/arp -a" or a DHCP lease table.  If you go the arp route you will on find addresses that your system has recently received/sent packets to, the DHCP lease table will give you the ability to see everything.  Though if it's static configured it won't show up.